# How do I merge hand-coded WSDL with the generated one?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I have a had-coded WSDL file with `<wsdl:documentation>` and other comments.  I wanted that to be published except with the `<soap:address location="...">` changed for the service to match the server.

That way I get the documentation shown when someone does a `?wsdl` request.

Is that possible in JAX-WS standards or is it vendor specific?

Answer (score 0):

You may

1. copy paste generated by JAX-WS WSDL.
2. modify the WSDL by hand
3. modify your service to expose you modified WSDL instead of the generated one.

`@WebService(..., wsdlLocation="WEB-INF/wsdl/my.wsdl")`

Alternatively you may hack METRO to interfere WSDL generation, but they may change the API any moment and I wouldn't recommend it.

```
com.sun.xml.ws.api.wsdl.writer.WSDLGeneratorExtension
```